# Biography of Galois in English

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, reference-request, 19th-century, galois

<sup>**Note**: This was first posted at Mathematics Stack Exchange, from which I was redirected here. Forgive me if this violates any crossposting rules I'm not currently aware of.</sup>

---

Currently, I'm starting work on a project about Evariste Galois. While I'm familiar with the basic details of his life — French, revolutionary, genius, headstrong, dead — and those details paint an amazing picture of him, I have not been able to find a comprehensive biography of him in English.

Unfortunately, my command of French is  poor and, thus, reading any biographies in French would be out of the question at this time. I was hoping you could point me to an authoritative biography in English, if such a thing exists, and if not, to compilations of his personal correspondence or the like.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, "dead" tends to be the last detail of many people's lives. Anyway, have you looked at the book by Leopold Infeld, "For Whom the Gods Love"?

Comment: It seems doubly difficult to do this when you don't read French.

Comment: While I love the French language, I'm only beginning to learn it, so I'm not what one would consider fluent in 'common' French, let alone the old-timey and mathematical sort of French that Galois doubtlessly used to express himself.

Comment: See Rothman's [Genius and Biographers: the Fictionalization of Evariste Galois](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Rothman84-106.pdf), which dispels many anecdotes that accumulated around Galois's biography, in particular due to E.T. Bell's and Infeld's fiction, based on modern scholarship.

Answer (score 5):

You can see :

- Laura Toti Rigatelli, [Evariste Galois 1811–1832](https://books.google.it/books?id=zCjyBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1996).

See also :

- Peter M. Neumann (editor), [The Mathematical Writings of Évariste Galois](https://books.google.it/books?id=fMh4KDMD_68C&printsec=frontcover) (2011); there is a general Introduction as well as specific introductions to the  original papers : all in English.

Answer (score 3):

The classical source is Leopold Infeld, Whom the gods love,
[https://www.amazon.com/Whom-Gods-Love-mathematics-education/dp/0873531256](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873531256)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the books of Bell, Infeld or Rigatelli is, as remarked by  Rothman's "Genius and Biographers: the Fictionalization of Evariste Galois", you can't trust the details in the narrative; they are often invented, by the author or by someone else.

Peter Neumann's "The Mathematical Writings of Évariste Galois" is the best one in English for Galois' writing.

The dozen pages "Historical Introduction/The Life of Galois" in Ian Stewart's "Galois Theory (fourth edition)" is the best biography of Galois in English that I have ever read: quite long, no invention of fictional details, no fact errors.